# Examples of Unicode String comparisons compared to the .NET framework default

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, culture, case-insensitive

I'm looking for some examples of *how* and *when* smart people do a Unicode comparison of strings, versus the framework default.

Since many people don't work with strings from other cultures, here are a few interesting comparison examples I found.

1. .ToUpper()

   - The lowercase Turkish 'i' converts to an uppercase İ (U+0130)
2. Equals

   - The uppercase version of the Turkish example above
3. Comparing equality for the last word in a sentence

   - Hebrew treats the last letter in a sentence differently then how it would be represented in Arabic
4. ... other examples ...

**Question**
What comparisons are common in the Unicode world?  (feel free to expand on the language examples)

What situations should I use (or not use) culture insensitive comparisons?  This seems to boil down to either a "linguistic", or a "non-linguistic/(binary)" operation.

- How does this relate to security and checking usernames/passwords.
- How and *when* does one choose between linguistic operations and non-linguistic operations?

I'm particularly interested how this would affect Chinese and other eastern languages.

**References**
While researching this question, I came across these sites

[Joel on Software: What every developer should know about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

[Strings In .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Best practices doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx

Comment: +1 Interesting. Seems to supercede "New Recommendations for Strings in .NET 2.0" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx ... Has anyone, with more experience than myself, compared the differences? If so, please post!